# is it possible to disable playback in itunes?

Tags: itunes, windows, settings

I have an old 3rd generation iPod Nano I use for the gym. I don't have an iPhone and the only reason I use iTunes is to add/delete podcasts to my iPod. I don't listen to any music or watch movies or television shows from iTunes and really don't use.

Here's the problem. Whenever I plug my iPod into my computer (Windows 7), iTunes messes up the sound settings on my computer. My friends come over  and we record our music or whatever for fun. I have an Asus Essence ST sound card on my computer and every time i plug in my iPod iTunes starts up and messes up with sound settings.

Is there a way to completely disable playback on iTunes and or disable iTunes from accessing my sound card?

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on the "messes up" part? What is iTunes doing exactly to your sound settings?

Comment: @BartArondson if I plug my iPod in iTunes and add/delete some podcasts then start to record something with my friends, the recording audio is messed up and not right. I have uninstall and reinstall the sound card drivers to get it back to normal. After I reinstall the sound card drivers everything works great. I'm not sure about the technical details but this is the best way i can describe the problem.